# MVC 5: Loading content area via Ajax and modify browser url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-5

In my _Layout.cshtml page I have few links on left side of the page and a main content area on the right side of the page, when clicking the links only the content area should get updated. I don’t want to reload full page.

I tried loading partial views using Ajax

So in my _Layout.cshtml page

Here is the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return link_click()">Click here</a>
```

Content area div

```
<div class="page-content">
            @RenderBody()
            @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</div>
```

And then loading content area via Ajax call

```
function link_click() {

         $('.page-content').load('/Home/Register);
         return false;
     }
```

From MVC controller : I simply returns partial view.

My questions:

1. This approach works fine, however problem is that Url on browser remains same. I need to modify browser Url according to content page so that users can bookmark the page and use back/forward browser buttons for history. How would browser Url get modify ?
2. I did some research on google and find jQuery plugins Pjax and Pajax which uses HTML5 pushstate technology along with Ajax, but I am not sure which one is better solution (Pjax or PAjax) ? Also examples demonstrating Pjax and Pajax are quite dated. Any latest technology / pattern to achieve above?
3. I wan't to avoid using SPA frameworks like AngularJS, Knockout etc as using these frameworks requires several approval in my company and I want to avoid that.

Any help or suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change url along with your view, you could use `window.history.pushState()` function.

The use of the function is following:

```
window.history.pushState(
    { state: 'someState' }, // any object, that can be retrieved
    'Page title', // new page title
    '/Home/Register' // new url
);
```

You can use this this way:

```
function link_click() {

         $('.page-content').load('/Home/Register', function() {
            window.history.pushState(
                null,
                'Page title', // new page title
                '/Home/Register' // new url
            )
         });

         return false;
     }
```

This will cause a new state will be pushed into backstack. It allows user to go back into previous page, by just clicking back button. But this is what you need to handle by yourself, to i.e. load the previous view. 
To do this, you need to set a handler, which will be invoked when user goes back:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```

State object is the same, that you defined when pushing new page into backstack.

If you don't want to push a new page into backstack, you can replace it using `window.history.replaceState`.

Comment: Your solution perfectly works for me..This is exactly what I was looking for. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

[There](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/) is a simple jQuery plugin.

Just include it on your page.

Modify your links to:

```
<a href="#link">Click here</a>
```

And in script block begin to listen for address changes:

```
$.address.change(function (event) {
    //it works perfect for url with complex hash like this: http://....#?departmentid=10&employeeid=15
    if(location.hash == '#link')
    {
         $('.page-content').load("@Url.Action("Register","Home")");
    }
}
```

> The function receives a single event object parameter that contains
>   the following properties: value, path, pathNames, parameterNames,
>   parameters and queryString.

There are more solutions like angular, backbone and etc, but you wrote you got problems with them, so it is just jQuery.